# No me funciona el query al llamar los datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Problema:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejemplo\Pag\PagBase\Part5.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejemplo\Pag\PagBase\Part5.php on line 21

Por alguna razón no me esta funcionando el query, no trae los datos guardados en la base usando esta forma, y no se como hacer para editarlos.

Codigo pag 5:

```
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
include("Conexiones.php");
include("funciones.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
sleep(2);
$genero         = $_POST["genero"];
$nombre         = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo         = $_POST["correo"];
$correo1        = $_POST["correo1"];
$celular        = $_POST["celular"];
$fnacimiento    = $_POST["fnacimiento"];
$pais           = "1";
$ciudad         = "-----";
$peso           = $_POST["peso"];
$estatura       = $_POST["estatura"];
$actividadxx    = $_POST["unica"];
$distribuidor   = 'Admin';
$fechahoy       = date("Y-m-d");
$sql_consulta = $enlace->query("SELECT * FROM t000terceros WHERE correo = '$correo';");
$rst_consulta = $sql_consulta->num_rows;
```

Y codigo conexiones:

```
class Conexion{
public static function Conectar(){
$this->user = "root";
$this->pass = "1";
$this->host = "localhost";
$this->ddbb = "enlace";
try {
    $enlace = new mysqli(
    $this->host,
    $this->user,
    $this->pass,
    $this->ddbb
);
return $enlace;
    }catch (Exception $e){
        die("El error de conexion es: ". $e->getMessage());
    }}}
```

Comment: Hola. La conexión es devuelta desde el método `Conectar()`, pero nunca llamas a ese método. Prueba a poner esto antes de llamar a `query()`: **`$enlace=Conexion::Conectar();`** eso hará que el objeto de conexión que te devuelve el método esté en `$enlace` y podrás usarlo posteriormente. También puedes hacer la llamada directa si prefieres.

Comment: Hola @Sebastián, Bienvenido, te recomiendo el [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct)